# Magento upgrade from 2.3 to 2.3.1 via CLI error

Tags: magento2

Getting following error while compilation.

```
In Generator.php line 218:

  Source class "\Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductField" for "Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\P  
  roductFieldMapper" generation does not exist.
```

Comment: Are you getting it in terminal ?

Comment: Yes. This upgrade is via CLI. So obviously terminal.

Comment: Are you able to find type="Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductField" in any di.xml file?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same issue and I solved this by disabling all Amasty plugins

```
bin/magento module:disable Amasty_Shopby Amasty_ShopbyPage Amasty_ShopbyBrand
```

If you have extra modules of Amasty you should disable them too. After this, I could compile normally without any issues. I already send a message to Amasty that they need to look at this problem as more people are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But I really don't see any reference to Amasty in the code. I was able to solve by disabling Magento_Elasticsearch6 module.

Comment: This is bug of Magento 2.3.1, plugin is declared in di.xml file of Elasticseach6 module but class file is missing.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue I have created one class file at app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper;

use Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapperInterface;
use Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper
    as Elasticsearch5ProductFieldMapper;

/**
 * Class ProductFieldMapper
 */
class ProductFieldMapper extends Elasticsearch5ProductFieldMapper implements FieldMapperInterface
{
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as a temporary fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

None of those are actual fix. This happening because magento is trying to apply plugins without checking for concrete classes. And it generates virtual types automatically. A fix would be to upgrade to 2.3.2

Here is the fix https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22046/commits/fa079c94c9c0a6d3cd7d9dca3b52d3394de50934